# Loopback PeristentModel.findOne returns NaN Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am new to Node.js and loopback framework. What I am trying to achieve is find one model instance in loopback (Job Model here) that matches filter specification.

Link: https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-findone

Here is my code:

job.json file:

```
"properties": {
    "jobname": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  }
```

worker.js file

```
var app = require('../server');
let Job = app.models.Job;
async function jobListener() {

    console.log('1');
    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    let query = { jobname: "countProvider"}
     Job.findOne({ where: query }, function(err, jobResult) {
         if(err) {
             console.log('Error', err);
         }
        // console.log(typeof jobResult);
        // console.log('Test');
     });

    while (jobResult) { 
        console.log('11111');
        await sleep(5000);
        console.log('checking for job in mongodb with a delay of 5 seconds');
    }
}

 jobListener();
```

But when I tried to print the typeof jobResult and doing console.log('Test'); I am getting NaN. Can Somebody help me where I am wrong. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is `sleep` function? Why you are using callback with query even when you can use `await` with it! And what is the need of `while` here? Please explain  why do you need and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Actually I am trying to run nodejs child process in background. sleep function is used for sleeping  for 5 seconds if Job is not found. Used while loop because if there is any document in Job Model available. Please correct me If I am wrong.  How can i use await with it?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Actually in loopback we are using where clause for querying. https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#where-clause-for-queries